# Is it possible that two users report the same timezone name in the format "America/New_York" but one is observing DST and other isn't?

Tags: android, ios, cron, timezone, dst

I'm working on creating cron jobs which need to be fire according to a user's local time. I'm using an online cron job service which lets us set the timezone names as "America/New_York" etc. specific to cron jobs.

So, the question is, is it possible that two users report the same timezone name but one is observing DST and other is not? We'll get these timezone names from Android and iOS users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  "America/New_York" is an IANA time zone name, and these time zones go on or off daylight saving at a particular UTC instant in time.  Assuming both users agree on the current UTC time, and on the time zone, then they then must agree on the current local time.